# Resize H1, H2... tags according to themselves, not the parent element

Tags: html, css

This is probably a very simple and frenquently-asked question, but I'm not finding the right keywords to search: I have the following code:

```
        <div id="bloquetexto4" class="bloquetexto">
        <H2><b>TITULO</b></H2>
        <p>Texto bla bla bla.</p>
```

And this CSS:

```
.bloquetexto p { 
    font-size: 110%;
    color: orange;
}
.bloquetexto h2 { font-size: 90%; }
```

I only want the H2 element to be slightly smaller than what it would be in normal circunstances, but when I add this, the H2 turns in fact into a much smaller text, certainly much less than 90% of its usual size (I've made a JsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/c6hzghcq/).

I understand that this is because, when you add a `font-size`, the H2's size is calculated according to the font size in **the parent element**, so in the above case, the H2 size would be 90% of the parent element's regular text size. My question is: how can I make it so that it calculates the size according to itself? (As I said: I just want the H2 to be a bit smaller than it would usually be, regardless of the size of other elements in the page).

Comment: You can add a class and then .classname h2{give font-size } which won't affect another h2

Comment: the default in most browser for a H2 element is "font-size: 1.5em;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set an H2 Element most browser has a standard setting, wich can find in [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp), for H2 is this 1.5em;

```css
  .bloquetexto p {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: orange;
  }
  .bloquetexto h2 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    /*Smaller text because standard is 1.5em;*/
  }
```

```html
<div id="bloquetexto4" class="bloquetexto">
  <H2><b>TITULO</b></H2>
  <p>Texto bla bla bla.</p>
```

EDIT::
You also should use a "reset" stylesheet wich can be very handfull because not all browser are the same..

Answer (score 1):

Use `px`, `em` or anything else, instead `%`. Because `%` as you know, get the height of parent.